# Proof of solvable constrained optimization with a subset of a larger set of constraints

Tags: optimization, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

Way out of my comfort zone here so apologies if I'm not providing enough or correct information. I work with an application of constrained optimization to assemble test forms ([automated](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/jedm.12262?casa_token=RyH_FNh8dLoAAAAA:oxok_Wdl7QgD67tkaGpUSJbgwbhFy_95l4n1sGDItSexxFbHUIlEZ-i0-lOjttPg2qRX7D4TlMbe) [test](https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/handle/20.500.12657/54168/1/9781317975892.pdf#page=149) [assembly](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1207/s15327574ijt0503_8?casa_token=oG4SJwOngQYAAAAA:Vr28MAiuVh8NKAKQecKlLZA9-BQLXg5huuPpbgkt0_KB1RGA-12XkpumS2i9EunAz2Tr0VVkTZg)). I have an intuitive understanding of the fact that, if there is a feasible solution to a constrained optimization problem with, say, K constraints, that there will also be a feasible solution to the same problem with any subset of those K constraints, but I'm interested in whether there is a formal proof of this. My understanding is that any subset of those K constraints represent a more relaxed problem in a sense, so if the more constrained or difficult problem is solvable then any more relaxed problem nested in that problem is also solvable. (Not necessarily that it produces the same solution -- it's ok for the solution to be different -- just that it's still solvable.) Does anyone know of any formal proofs of this? Or can anyone point me toward any reading that discusses this? I have a background in applied statistics and educational psychology but will do my best to digest the more complex math that I am almost certain (with dread) this will entail. :)

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a solution that satisfies all constraints, then *the same solution* also satisfies any subset of constraints, so your original feasible solution is also feasible for any subset of constraints. Of course, as you say, there may still be a better one, but just this one proves feasibility (optimality, or boundedness, is another story).